# How to get width of Popup thats in the ComboBox template

Tags: c#, wpf

I have this IMultiValueConverter that I would like to figure out the width of a ComboBox when it list changes values.

I have looked at the MSDN ComboBox template and can see that there is a Popup, with the x:Name="Popup", actually it's a bit confusing at the top of the page they call it PART_Popup. [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752094%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

How can I get the Popup object in order to determine its width? If the Popup is not an option for whatever reason, what about the Grid that is inside it.

I have seen that others before have iterated through all the items looking for the max length in textual rendering, I'd like to try this way if possible.

```
public class ComboBoxWidthConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        double cbxWidth = 100;

        if (values[0] == null || values[1] == null)
            return cbxWidth;

        ComboBox cb = (ComboBox)values[0];

        int itemCount = (int)values[1];

        if (itemCount == 0)
            return cbxWidth;

        //Find popup and retrieve width.

        return cbxWidth;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you first have to call cb.IsOpen = "True" 
and then search for a child , But i'm not sure it's in the Visual tree ..
I would bind it in the cb's template to some element i can't reference as a child as cb.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is an incorrect use of a Converter, maybe if you could elaborate why you need to get the width of the popup, there might be a better solution for that. Usually in WPF if you can't do something straightforward (like accessing the `Popup` element of a `ComboBox`) you are trying to do something wrong.

Comment: On loading my program, the ComboBox is not populated with anything. I have a DataGrid with buttons in the column headers that opens up my own Popup. Upon opening the popup the ComboBox gets filled with items that relate to that column. This one popup is used for all columns.

Comment: I don't think it's incorrect I've seen a few examples of control properties being set by converters. I suppose I could have done it in the button behavior that opens the popup and populates the combobox, but it doesn't make much difference right now where it is, I'm just trying to make it work. Any ideas?

Comment: @eranotzap IsOpen is for a Popup, cb in the code is a ComboBox. Not sure I understand the second piece.

Comment: @Hank your right i ment this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.combobox.isdropdownopen(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Hank did you create the Tempalte for your ComboBox or is it the default one ?

Comment: Just tried this but no luck returns a null: Popup pop = (Popup)cb.Template.FindName("Popup", cb);

Comment: @Hank Because ComboBox is not loaded yet.

Comment: @Hank , why do you need the popup width ? 
 we can think of a better way of doing this.

Comment: Maybe. As I mentioned the items don't get populated straight away, so it goes to a default width of approx 50px, when they are populated, the width of the ComboBox or I should say the TextBlock stays the same. The width needs to get updated as the ComboBox's items as updated.

Comment: @Hank - I would create some sort of behavior or modify the template of the combobox ,I gave you something for your question , but if you  Tell me what exactly you trying to achieve we can find a better solution .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works : you might think of a way to integrate it in your Converter.

```
  void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
       // comboBox is an element in 'MainWindow'
       var popup = VisualTreeHelperExtensions.FindVisualChild<Popup>(comboBox);
  }

  public static T FindVisualChild<T>(DependencyObject depObj) where T : Visual
    {
        if (depObj != null && IsVisual(depObj))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
            {
                DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);

                if (child != null && child is T)
                {
                    return (T)child;
                }

                foreach (T childOfChild in FindVisualChildren<T>(child))
                {
                    return childOfChild;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }    

    public static IEnumerable<T> FindVisualChildren<T>(DependencyObject depObj) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        if (depObj == null)
            yield break;

        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
        {
            if (IsVisual(depObj))
            {
                DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);

                if (child != null && child is T)
                {
                    yield return (T) child;
                }

                foreach (T childOfChild in FindVisualChildren<T>(child))
                {
                    yield return childOfChild;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static bool IsVisual(DependencyObject depObj)
    {
        return depObj is Visual || depObj is Visual3D;
    }
```

Comment: IsVisual() is not recognized

Comment: and FindVisualChildren()